# Move executable from application bundle to system location

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, executable

In my cocoa application, i am trying to push a third party executable file to this /usr/libexec/cups  location. For that , i have added this third party executable file in my bundle and successfully moved the file to that location when i run my application.

But the executable is not performing the same operation like when i install the third party installer package. if i manually copy the executable file to the location, it works fine by repairing the permission.

**Edited :**

Now i found that the executable file is altered in application package contents. Don't know how it get altered. what is the safest way to move a executable from  application bundle to application content without getting altered.

Note that : I have disabled the sandbox mode in my application.

Comment: As a user, I wouldn't expect an application to replace the system-provided cups in /usr/libexec, so is there a reason you're doing it?

Comment: No, i am not replacing system-provided cups. I am including my executable inside the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do this complex steps. Use package maker, include your executables and application, apply the permission and create a .pkg file. If you are not releasing in mac store , its best to release the app in .pkg format using package maker.